# Binary Tree to Heap Tree Conversion - Stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, heap

While working on a problem, I have tried the following solution. Somehow my output is stuck into infinite loop and not printing result or updated heap tree.

Given a tree where the left and right subtrees are min heaps, but the root node does not maintain the min heap property. Your code should modify the tree rooted at Node* n so it is a min heap. (This means you need to satisfy the min heap property:
it is okay for a node's value to be equal to one or both of its children, but the node's value must not be greater than either of its children. You do not have to try to balance the tree or make it a complete tree.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

You have the following class Node already defined.
You cannot change this class definition, so it is
shown here in a comment for your reference only:

class Node {
public:
  int value;
  Node *left, *right;
  Node(int val = 0) { value = val; left = right = nullptr; }
  ~Node() {
    delete left;
    left = nullptr;
    delete right;
    right = nullptr;
  }
};

This function has also previously been defined for you:

void printTreeVertical(const Node* n);

You can use it to print a verbose, vertical diagram of
a tree rooted at n. In this vertical format, a left child
is shown above a right child in the same column. If no
child exists, [null] is displayed.

*/

void downHeap(Node *n) {
    Node *curr = new Node();
    Node *mino = new Node();

  if (n == nullptr ){
    return;
  } else if (n->left->value > n->value & n->right->value > n->value){
    return;
  // } else if (n->left== nullptr & n->right== nullptr) {
  //   return;

  //   } 
  } else {
    // node* curr = new Node(n)
    // n = new Node((std::min(n->left->value, n->right->value));
    // if (n->left->value)
    while(n->left!= nullptr & n->right!= nullptr){
      if (n->left == nullptr){
        mino = n->right;
      } else if (n->right == nullptr) {
        mino = n->left;
      } else {
        mino = (std::min(n->left, n->right));
      }

      std::cout << n->value << std::endl;
      std::cout << mino->value << std::endl;




        if(n->value > mino-> value){
            curr->value = n->value;
            n->value = mino->value;
            mino->value = curr->value;
            std::cout << n->value << std::endl;
            std::cout << mino->value << std::endl;
            downHeap(mino);
          }
        }
        return;
      }
  }

  // Implement downHeap() here.



// You can also use this compact printing function for debugging.
void printTree(Node *n) {
  if (!n) return;
  std::cout << n->value << "(";
  printTree(n->left);
  std::cout << ")(";
  printTree(n->right);
  std::cout << ")";
}

int main() {
  Node *n = new Node(100);
  n->left = new Node(1);
  n->left->left = new Node(3);
  n->right = new Node(2);
  n->right->left = new Node(3);
  n->right->right = new Node(4);
  n->right->right->right = new Node(5);
  std::cout << std::endl << "BEFORE - Vertical printout:" << std::endl;
  printTreeVertical(n);

  downHeap(n);

  std::cout << "Compact printout:" << std::endl;
  printTree(n);
  std::cout << std::endl << " AFTER Vertical printout:" << std::endl;
  printTreeVertical(n);

  delete n;
  n = nullptr;

  return 0;
}
```

Please suggest what I am missing. I feel I am making it too complicated. Also, I do not have any other function like swap for converting the binary tree into heap min. I am not using an array or vector as well. So, if you can provide me simple solution I will appreciate it.

Comment: Load your program in the debugger, and single-step it. That will show you *exactly* where things are going off the rails. If you don't know how to use your debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: `mino = (std::min(n->left, n->right));` is probably an error. I think you want `n->left->value` and `n->right->value`. Also, in `(n->left== nullptr & n->right== nullptr)`, you probably want `&&`. Same thing a few lines above that. Finally, edit your question to fix the indentation. I think the problem is that your `return` in `downHeap` is outside the `while` body, which could cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @JimMischel I want to return mino as node which is smallest of left and right children of root. If I use -> value, it will only return integer and note node. Please correct me or let me know better method.

Comment: I see the problem. What you really want is the node that has the smallest value. You cannot do that with `std::min`. You need to compare the values and return the node. `if (node->left->value < node->right->value) return node->left; else return node->right;`

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks. Exactly. That was the problem. its fixed like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is this line of code:

```
    mino = (std::min(n->left, n->right));
```

Here, you're comparing two pointers when you really want to compare the values in the two objects you're referring to, and return a pointer to the object that has the smaller value. That is:

```
mino = (n->left->value < n->right->value) ? n->left : n->right;
```

Also in this line of code:

```
} else if (n->left->value > n->value & n->right->value > n->value){
```

You probably want `&&` (logical AND) rather than `&` (bitwise AND). See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-the-differences-between-bitwise-and-logical-and-operators-in-cc/.

Finally, your code formatting is a little off so it's difficult to tell, but it looks like the `return` statement is outside the `while` loop in your `downHeap` function. If it is outside the loop body, then that could lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the easiest solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for complete solution.

```
void downHeap(Node *n) {
  // check if it is a leaf node
  if (n->left == NULL && n->right == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  if ((n->left != NULL) && (n->right != NULL)) {
    if ((n->value <= n->left->value) && (n->value <= n->right->value)) {
      return;
    } 
  }

  // Node passed in is not a leaf
  // If left is null, we can focus on the right first
  // If the right node has a greater value
  if (n->right != NULL) {
    if ((n->left == NULL) && (n->right->value < n->value)) {
      int rightnodevalue = n->right->value;
      int nodevalue = n->value;

      n->value = rightnodevalue;
      n->right->value = nodevalue;

      if (n->right != NULL) {
        downHeap(n->right);
        return;
      }  
    }
  }


  // Node passed in is not a leaf
  // Left is not null
  // First check if right is null
  // If right is null, we can focus on the left first
  // If the left node has a greater value
  if (n->left != NULL) {
    if ((n->right == NULL) && (n->left->value < n->value)) {
      int leftnodevalue = n->left->value;
      int nodevalue = n->value;

      n->value = leftnodevalue;
      n->left->value = nodevalue;

      if (n->left != NULL) {
        downHeap(n->left);
        return;
      }
    }
  }


  // Node passed in is not a leaf
  // Left is not null
  // Right is not null
  // If left is less than right
  if ((n->left != NULL) && (n->right != NULL)) {
    if (n->left->value < n->right->value) {
      int leftnodevalue = n->left->value;
      int nodevalue = n->value;

      n->value = leftnodevalue;
      n->left->value = nodevalue;

      if (n->left != NULL) {
        downHeap(n->left);
        return;
      }
    }
    else {
      // Proceed to swap the parent and the right node
      // Reference pointers for child's pointers
      int rightnodevalue = n->right->value;
      int nodevalue = n->value;

      n->value = rightnodevalue;
      n->right->value = nodevalue;

      if (n->right != NULL) {
        downHeap(n->right);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a helper function to swap node values, you can make your code a lot cleaner and implement recursion quite easily. For example:

```
// DEFINE HELPER FUNCTION
void compareSwap(Node *a, Node *b) {
    int temp;
    if (a->value > b->value) {
        temp = b->value;
        b->value = a->value;
        a->value = temp;
    }
    return;
}

void downHeap(Node *n) {
  Node *compNode;

// 1. n is a leaf
    if (!n->left && !n->right) {
        return;
    }

// 2. n has one left child
  else if (n->left && !n->right) {
    if (n->value > n->left->value) {
      compareSwap(n, n->left);
      downHeap(n->left);
    }
    return;
  }

// 3. n has one right child
  else if (!n->left && n->right) {
    if (n->value > n->right->value) {
      compareSwap(n, n->right);
      downHeap(n->right);
    }
    return;
  }

// 4. n has two children ... (n->left && n->right) 
    else {
    // HEAP IS SATISFIED, RETURN NOTHING
        if ((n->value <= n->left->value) && (n->value <= n->right->value)) {
            return;
        }
    // RIGHT IS LESS THAN n BUT LEFT IS NOT, SWAP RIGHT
    else if (((n->value <= n->left->value) && (n->value > n->right->value))) {
      compareSwap(n, n->right);
      downHeap(n->right);
      return;
    }
    // LEFT IS LESS THAN n BUT RIGHT IS NOT, SWAP LEFT
    else if (((n->value > n->left->value) && (n->value <= n->right->value))) {
      compareSwap(n, n->left);
      downHeap(n->left);
      return;
    }
    // BOTH ARE LESS THAN, SWAP MIN
    else {
      compNode = (n->left->value < n->right->value) ? n->left : n->right; 
      compareSwap(n, compNode);
      downHeap(compNode);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```